# SMTP Mail Trigger is not working in lumen

Tags: php, lumen-5.2

I am trying to do a mail trigger using smtp credentials but it shows

> Connection could not be established with host
>   email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com.php_network_getaddresses:
>   getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known #0.

Comment: This pretty much means your server does not know who the smtp server is, looks like an internal server misconfiguration, a dns issue.
Contact your host about this, they'll know what to do or if you are on a vps with root access, edit /etc/resolv.conf and add google's nameservers in the file, see https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/usingv

Comment: My port is 465 and host is email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com and also i was checked for other port also but not working

Comment: Kindly send me a google nameservers previous link is not opening

Comment: https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using

Comment: I had add the nameserver but it showing the same error.

Comment: I had added the following  nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8888
nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8844 in /etc/resolv.conf. But it shows the same error. Kindly any one clarify it.

Comment: Kindly any one give the explanation about the above issue.